# Artifact "Windows Machine File Copy" task configure properly

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, build-automation, devops, release-management

I just tried to automate my build process. So tried to add **Windows Machine File Copy** task for artifact (Release Definition)

This **DevOpsBuild** artifact has 3 environment as seen on the picture.

[image]

So I added **Windows Machine File Copy** task to **copy the files** from my published folder

> \localhost\NewBuildDropLocation\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)/drop/MVCWebApplication/MVCWebApplication

So as example

> \localhost\NewBuildDropLocation\DevOpsBuild\20180427.3\drop\MVCWebApplication\MVCWebApplication

here the image of above settings

[image]

then after I create release for this artifact, it's stuck "In Progress" phase not going for other phases.

[image]

I'm using **localhost** environment for all these task. I'm newbie to DevOps, followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vev3Czaa1pA&index=4&list=LLmNSjiYxAfWCNH593ELdtxA&t=616s)

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` is the **machine the agent is running on**.

The source parameter should be **the location of the build artifacts**, which is usually `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, or some subfolder of that. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables) for more details.

The **Machines** parameter should be an actual hostname for a server on your network.

Also note that if you're using the Hosted agent, none of this is going to work -- if you're deploying to on-prem servers, the servers have to be network-accessible by the agent. The hosted agent is run by Microsoft and lives in the cloud and definitely doesn't have access to your servers. You'll need to configure a private [agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents?view=vsts#install).